# how to update rows older than 30 seconds or 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to update MySQL rows older than 30 seconds or 30 minutes.

```
$sql = "SELECT C.sessid, C.datetime, U.username, U.firstname, U.lastname, U.sessid FROM checkins C, users U WHERE U.sessid = C.sessid AND SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 00:01:00')>C.datetime";
$result = mysql_query( $sql );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
mysql_query("UPDATE checkins SET status = 'was in'");
}
```

Here I have joined tables, just the users table and checkins table.
I am using subtime to determine the time difference and trying to update rows of checkins table if the C.datetime is older than 1 minute just for a test

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE checkins c join
       users u
       on c.sessid = u.sessid
    SET status = 'was in'
    WHERE c.datetime < now() - interval 30 second;
```

The `users` table is probably not needed, unless you require it for filtering.

Just change the `30 second` to `30 minute` for a 30 minute interval.

Comment: thanks for the assistance gordon although still cant get it to go, i am using  date("Y-m-d H:i:s") for c.datetime

Comment: You should be storing dates in the database using `datetime`, not as strings.

Comment: i didnt use datetime because it always returns 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: this does not work unfortunately. sorry.

Comment: @morty . . . You should fix your data so date/time values are stored in native format.